# Disabling Hanging Script

Tags: linux, bash, user-input

When launching a bash script in LINUX, the script succeeds and is successful, yet the terminal hangs. I must always input CTRL+C to end the program. I am able to type in the terminal and press enter, but the script does not respond.

I can not change the script files, but can I launch it so that it disables waiting for the user? Any troubleshooting tips to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure it hangs? Have you tried hitting enter a few times instead of ctrl-c?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it's successful, but hanging.  I think you need to investigate a bit further.  @thatotherguy makes a good point that it may be returning control to the shell but not showing your prompt line for one of various possible reasons.

Comment: "Hanging" but "successful" is not normal.  I understand that you say you cannot "change the script", but you should find out what is in it that goes wrong and why.  To get the best help here, you may want to post the script or, better yet, just post the minimal part of the script that reproduces the "hanging" behavior.

Comment: I have tried echo hello, prinf "hello", exit, logout, nothing works, it just moves to a new line upon ENTER being hit.

Comment: I am even able to move up to previous text and over right the cout of the process. I have not made the script files and do not have root rights, another company did, and they did not bother changing this behaviour, they just documented to press CTRL C to exit the process.

Comment: Perhaps the script includes a `wait` for some background processes that it started, or an `ssh` with X-forwarding enabled that left behind some forwarded connections, or any number of other things. No way to tell without actually seeing some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the script with `&` at the end, this will give the control back to the shell (executes the script as a background process).

```
./script.sh &
```

If you want to stop the script, you need to get its process id and then kill it. To get the process id, either execute `ps aux | grep script` where `script` is your script name, or execute `echo $!` right after you launched the script. When you have the process id, you can kill the process with `kill 1234` where `1234` is the process id.

If the execution time of the script can be estimated, you can kill it automatically after a certain amount of time:

```
bash -c '(sleep 5m; kill $$ 2> /dev/null) & exec script' &
```

In this command `sleep 5m` is the time after the process will be killed, and `script` is the name of your script (or the command).

For example if the script's execution time is 30 seconds on average, then you can set the timeout to a minute or two to give it some extra time in case the execution is slower than usual. Note that this command doesn't guarantee that the script finished its execution, so use it with care.

Comment: -1 This is not sustainable. Leaving hanging processes dormant would fill up the process table and available memory eventually.

Comment: How could I kill a background process if i used this method?

Comment: @tripleee If you have a better idea without the modification of the file, please make an answer. I know this solution is not the best, but seems to be the only option.

Comment: @user3652784 You can find the process id by running `ps aux` (you can filter the result with `ps aux | grep scriptname`) and kill it with `kill 1234` where `1234` is the process id of the script.

Comment: You can capture the value of `$!` just after starting the background process.

Comment: @user3652784 Updated my answer. I don't know what your script does, so timeout might not be a solution, but it's an other option you can try.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me and set everything up correctly